# ReactJS - replace / expire date card

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When entering 4 digits, you need to make a substitution and set a slash between the second and third digits. For example, I enter 1225 - I need get 12/25

```
changeInput(event) {
this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value.replace(/\/?/g, '').replace(/(\d{2})/, '$1/') });
}

<input type="text" inputMode="numeric" id="cardDate" name="cardDate" value={this.state.cardDate} autoComplete="off" maxLength="5" placeholder="MMYY" onChange={this.changeInput.bind(this)} />
```

I wrote a replacement code, but when I try to edit the input field, there is a problem. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the error code ??? Or tell us the error

Comment: The input field replaces 1225 with 12/25, but when I try to edit the input field - I can only delete 25 (the last two digits) and I cannot delete the slash ....

Comment: For example, the changed line of the card number (there are spaces added between every 4 digits), I can then change in the input field. There added trim()
      this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value.replace(/\s?/g, '').replace(/(\d{4})/g, '$1 ').trim() })

Probably, something else needs to be added to my replacement code so that after adding a slash, you can edit the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regex for this is a little bit overkill, there are a few ways to do this:
First, using String.prototype:

```
 String.prototype.insert = function (index, string) {
      if (index > 0) {
        return this.substring(0, index) + string + this.substr(index);
      }
    
      return string + this;
    };
    
const string = "1234";
const substring = string.insert(2, "/");
console.log(substring) // "12/34"
```

You can do it through an array too:

```
function replaceAt(string, index, toInsert) {
  const substring = [...string];
  substring.splice(2, 0, toInsert);
  return substring.join("");
}

const string = "1234";
const replaced = replaceAt(string, 1, "/");
console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: `replaceAt(string, index, toInsert) {
  const substring = [...string];
  substring.splice(2, 0, toInsert);
  return substring.join("");
}

changeInput(event) {
const replaced = this.replaceAt(event.target.value, 1, "/");
this.setState({ [event.target.name]: replaced });
}` - 1///11 - not work...

Comment: Make sure to pass the complete string and the proper index, you maybe calling the function without the complete string, because onChange is called every time the user types a character.